# Install custom maven plugin from local jar into local repository with dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-install-plugin

I have a maven plugin, which I have not uploaded to the central repository, but which I want to use in my projects.

**What works**

I can install the maven plugin like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/RudolfVonKrugstein/jinja-maven-plugin.git
cd jinja-maven-plugin
mvn install
```

Then I can use the plugin like this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.wintercloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.wintercloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>jinja-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.wintercloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>jinja-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>renderjinja</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFile>out.txt</outputFile>
                    <templateFile>templ.jinja</templateFile>
                    <varFile>vars.yaml</varFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here are the other files relevant to the compile:

templ.jinja:

```
{{ Name }}
```

vars.yaml:

```
Name: MyWonderfullName
```

This works:

```
> mvn compile
> cat out.txt
```

MyName

Nice!

**What does not work**

Now I am trying to give the plugin as a jar to my colleagues so that they can simple install the jar. The Idea is to do it like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/RudolfVonKrugstein/jinja-maven-plugin.git
cd jinja-maven-plugin
mvn package
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile=target/jinja-maven-plugin-1.0.jar
```

When I now do (in the sample project dir)

```
mvn compile
```

I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal de.wintercloud:jinja-maven-plugin:1.0:renderjinja (default) on project sample: Execution default of goal de.wintercloud:jinja-maven-plugin:1.0:renderjinja failed: A required class was missing while executing de.wintercloud:jinja-maven-plugin:1.0:renderjinja: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml
```

How can I install the jar so that I can use it as a plugin?
It looks to me as if dependencies are missing. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just hit [MINSTALL-110](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINSTALL-110), which is going to be fixed in the next 3.0.0 release of the Maven Install Plugin. The core issue here is that you're installing manually a JAR file with the [`file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#file) parameter, the plugin detects that there is a POM inside, but only keeps [the coordinate information](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) (group id, artifact id, packaging and version), not the whole POM. As such, when the POM is installed, the dependencies aren't kept.

Indeed, if you take a look at the installed POM, you will see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.wintercloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>jinja-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <description>POM was created from install:install-file</description>
</project>
```

which shows that the dependencies weren't retained. And if you take a look at the Maven logs in debug mode when running the `install-file` command, it will show

> [DEBUG] Using META-INF/maven/de.wintercloud/jinja-maven-plugin/pom.xml for groupId, artifactId, packaging and version

A work-around waiting for version 3.0.0 [is to specify the path to the POM file to install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/custom-pom-installation.html), along with the main artifact, by specifying the [`pomFile`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#pomFile) parameter. Run the following instead:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile=target/jinja-maven-plugin-1.0.jar -DpomFile=pom.xml
```

Then the full POM will be installed, not a generic stub.

With this change, the error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal de.wintercloud:jinja-maven-plugin:1.0:renderjinja (default) on project sample: Execution default of goal de.wintercloud:jinja-maven-plugin:1.0:renderjinja failed: A required class was missing while executing de.wintercloud:jinja-maven-plugin:1.0:renderjinja: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml

will not happen anymore. Maven will correctly download the dependencies and use them for the plugin.