# installing a jar with maven-install-plugin to local repo creates pom without dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-install-plugin

The jar I'm trying to install was built with maven and contains a complete pom.xml inside `META-INF/maven/<groupId>/<artifactId>`, including it's dependencies.

Eclipse does not resolve/see the transitive dependencies of that jar.

I tried to install both with and without pom generation.

Comment: But if you're saying what I think you're saying (you install a JAR manually with `mvn install:install-file` and used a dependency on it, expected the transitive dependencies to be resolved, and the POM inside the JAR to be used), please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960571/install-custom-maven-plugin-from-local-jar-into-local-repository-with-dependenci

Comment: Indeed. Let me see if I can get this to run with plugin version 2.6...

Comment: 3.0.0 isn't out yet (there is no version 2.6), so you'll need to extract the POM file from the JAR and refer to it with the `-DpomFile` parameter.

Comment: Sigh, ok. Thank you very much! Guess this was a duplicate, then. You can still convert to an answer, though...

Comment: No problem, duplicates like this one are great. It is short, clear and to the point. Perfect sign post for future people.